# Getting unexpected output while assigning a value to global variable php

Tags: php, global-variables

I'm trying to execute this php program but I'm getting an unexpected output.

```
<?php
$abc;
function test(){
    $abc="world";
}
test();
echo "hello ".$abc;?>
```

`Output : hello`
`Expected output : hello world`

I'm new to php. Please can any one tell me what mistake I made in this code.
I know that if I give `$abc="world"` out side the scope of `function test()` it will work.
What should I do to assign a value to global variable from a function ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: This is, in fact, the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `$abc` inside the class, and then access it using `$this`.

```
 <?php 
  class xyz {
   public $abc = '';
   function test(){
    $this->abc = "world";
  }
 }

$a = new xyz();
$a->test();
echo "hello ". $a->abc;
?>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/2fGWL4IC)

Answer (score 1):

Using global variables is generally considered to be bad practice, but you can use the `global` keyword to do this.

```
<?php
$abc;
function test(){
    global $abc;
    $abc="world";
}
test();
echo "hello ".$abc;?>
```

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this explain why please?  This is the correct answer and I indicated that it is bad practice to rely on global variables.

Answer (score 1):

`$abc` in `test` is local. If you want to access the global variable, you have to specify it, using `global $abc` inside your function.

see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the PHP compiler you want to use the global $abc variable like so:

```
$abc;
function test() {
    global $abc;
    $abc="world";
}
test();
```

because the scope of variables in php is different to that of javascript, for example, because you may have crossed over from there.

any variable defined within the function is naturally private to that function in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The $abc you're editing in test() is a different $abc than the global one. To fix your code the way you want it:

```
<?php
$abc;
function test(){
    global $abc;
    $abc="world";
}
test();
echo "hello ".$abc;
?>
```

Comment: Wow, someone went and downvoted all the global $abc answers? That's mature.